# Problems sorting dataframe in pandas, multiple column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner using python and pandas. I'm trying to save some results that I produced through a function. I'm having several problems at the moment to generate the dataframe with desired results. Here is an example of an iterable function that I wrote (To simplify the description I'm using the example of the area of several triangles. My real function is more complicated and has several intermediate steps):

```
Base = 5
H = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in H:

    def Triangle_area():

        H = [i]
        ratio = (Base*H)
        area = np.divide(ratio,2)

        ms = pd.DataFrame(area, columns=[i])
        A = ms[i].mean()
        A1 = pd.DataFrame({'area':A}, index=[i])

        return A1


    areas = Triangle_area()
    print(areas)
```

The result is a dataframe or a series of dataframes as follows:

```
   area
1   0.5
   area
2   1.0
   area 
3   1.5
   area
4   2.0
   area
5   2.5
```

But what I want should look like this:

```
H   area
1   0.5
2   1.0
3   1.5
4   2.0
5   2.5
```

I think that there must exist several ways to do this, but I can not find the way to do it. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: whats with the for loop? can you fix the example code so it can run please

Comment: Do you want an H column, or just the indices there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating and returning a new dataframe each time in your example, which is not what you want. Here is an example of your triangle program that will return one dataframe with the results. I hope this helps and you can find how to apply it to your problem, let me know if you need more help

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def Triangle_area(height, base):
    '''
    Calculate the area of a right angle triangle, Area(height, base) = (base*height)/2
    Put all results in pandas dataframe before returning
    '''
    H = np.array(height)    # Make numpy array of heights, easier for our computations
    ratio = H * base        
    area = ratio/2
    A1 = pd.DataFrame({'H': height, 'area':area}) # Turn results into pandas dataframe

    return A1 # return column


Base = 5
H = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

areas = Triangle_area(H, Base)
print(areas)
```

Comment: I think you forgot the 'H' column in the pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't notice that. Just assumed they were the indices of the dataframe. I'll add that thanks

Comment: Thank you, your approach let me see how to conduct my code and you explain my mistake!!

Comment: @JonathanPacheco awesome, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use vectorized approach first:

```
In [115]: def Triangle_area(base, h):
     ...:     return base * h / 2.
     ...:

In [116]: df = pd.DataFrame({'base':[1,2,3,4,5], 'h':[5]*5})

In [117]: df
Out[117]:
   base  h
0     1  5
1     2  5
2     3  5
3     4  5
4     5  5

In [118]: df['area'] = Triangle_area(df['base'], df['h'])

In [119]: df
Out[119]:
   base  h  area
0     1  5   2.5
1     2  5   5.0
2     3  5   7.5
3     4  5  10.0
4     5  5  12.5
```

Comment: Appreciated, a very good advice to define the function first and then the variables, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def Triangle_area():

    '''
    @param Base, scalar length of triangle base
    @param H, array of various triangle heights
    @returns A1, dataframe with columns 'H' and 'area'
        corresponding to height and area of triangle with 
        that height
    '''

    ratio = Base*np.array(H)
    area = np.divide(ratio,2)

    A1 = pd.DataFrame({'H':np.array(H),'area':area})

    return A1

areas = Triangle_area()
print(areas)
```

Here I tried to retain the same function and global variable names as you. A few tricks:

- Convert the list H into a NumPy array (NumPy works very well with pandas and I would recommend looking into it if you are not familiar with it already).
- Instead of using a `for loop`, operate on the arrays directly.